# Hibernate search quarkus compatibility questions

Tags: elasticsearch, quarkus, hibernate-search

Im working in a quarkus project, I have to connect to an elasticsearch clusert and in production exists a mysql database with data.
Im thinking about using Hibernate Search but I have some questions.

1-Which version of hibernate search use quarkus? In the pom is not specified. Is 6?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-search-orm-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2-It compatible with elasticsearch 7.11.1?

3-In my project I will connect to the mysql database just once to initialize all the index, then the connection is going to be closed, is this possible? or hibernate search needs to be connected to mysql database always?

4-To initialize the indexs with hibernate search is mandatory to use hibernate annotations (for example @Entity and @Column) in the entitys?

5-As I said, the connection with mysql database is going to be close after first indexing, is there a way to add new records to index if I get a list of objects from other system? (for example something like batch)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's Hibernate Search 6 - in Quarkus 1.13, 6.0.2.Final
2. Yes, it should be. Our main testing is now against the latest Open Source version of Elasticsearch but we are still testing 7.11.
3. Hibernate Search handles reads/writes and also hydrate your search data from the database so you should have the MySQL database around. If you are only doing read-only stuff AND only using projections, maybe not having the database around is possible but I don't think it's a supported use case
4. Yes.
5. You will have to implement it yourself, there's nothing built-in.

Comment: About 3, I just need Hibernate search for first index and query elasticsearch. Do you think that if the connection to mysql is lost it will give application problems?

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is the POJO version of Hibernate Search if you really want to be disconnected. Last time I checked it was still under development but Yoann, the lead of Search, can probably shed some light on this when he's back from PTO.

Comment: About 3, I'd say just try it. Depending on your configuration, Hibernate ORM may be able to create a session without using a JDBC connection, so as long as you don't rely on anything that requires a connection (e.g. loading an entity), it might just work. As Guillaume mentioned, though, it's definitely not a supported (read: tested) use case, and you will need to use [projections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-dsl-projection) to retrieve data about matched entities.

Comment: About 5, there is an experimental Hibernate Search "mapper" that allows you to index from any datasource, not just a database. But it's really in its early stages right now, so early in fact that we don't publish it to Maven. If you're interested, you can watch progress [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1800): we'll update the ticket when this gets resolved.